# How to display lines with Arrows on a FeatureLayer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've setup a feature service with a symbology.  One symbol is a line with an arrow at the end.  The description for such a symbol is not part of the FeatureServer response data.  So it is not supported?  I only see this (not sure why the width is 6):

```
UniqueValueInfos:
Value: Arrow 
Label: Arrow 
Description: 
Symbol:
Style: esriSLSSolid 
Color: [0, 0, 0, 255] 
Width: 6
```

If not supported, any tips on how I might proceed?  Perhaps a termination icon attribute and then some custom gfx code?  Anything already exist for this?